# Confusion with Haskell do blocks

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following code:

```
doSomething :: [Int] -> [Int]
doSomething arg = arg ++ [1]

afterThreeTurns = do
    first <- ["test"]
    doSomething [1] -- COMMENT THIS
    return first
```

This returns:

```
*Main> afterThreeTurns
["test","test"]
```

If I take out the line marked COMMENT THIS, it returns ["test"] as expected. Why? The way I see it doSomething should have no effect on first?

Comment: You should read up on the list monad. Also keep in mind that a non-binding expression in a do block is semantically the same as binding to a throwaway value like `_ <- doSomething [1]`

Comment: To answerers: as a novice, who has just been enlightened by the equivalence you've shown, I'd be 200% happier if there were some pointer for why or how these are equivalent. Nice answers and a comment though.

Comment: @Yosh `do` notation is equivalent to calls to `>>=` because that's just how it's defined. Before the code is compiled, the compiler actually changes all `do` notation into `>>=` calls. So, `do` really is just a convenient shorthand for calling `>>=` (and `>>`). `do { v <- m1; m2 v }` gets turned into `m1 >>= (\v -> m2 v)` and `do { m1; m2 }` is turned into `m1 >> m2` (also `do x` is always the same as `x`, for any single value or single bound variable `x`). I added that information to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `doSomething [1]` is `[2,1]`, your code is equivalent to:

```
afterThreeTurns = do
   first <- ["test"]
   x <- [2,1]
   return first
```

This is the same as the list comprehension `[ first | first <- ["test"], x <- [2,1] ]` which explains why you are getting a list of length 2.

Note that the variable `x` is not referenced anywhere, so this could also be written:

```
afterThreeTurns = do
   first <- ["test"]
   _ <- [2,1]
   return first
```

Here is an analogous case using the `IO` monad. The code:

```
thirdLine = do
  getLine
  getLine
  x <- getLine
  putStrLn $ "The third line is: " ++ x
```

is the same as:

```
thirdLine = do
  _ <- getLine
  _ <- getLine
  x <- getLine
  putStrLn $ "The third line is: " ++ x
```

You can get ghc to flag these kinds of monadic statements with the  `-fwarn-unused-do-bind` compiler flag. In your example ghc will emit the warning:

```
...: Warning:
    A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ‘Int’
    Suppress this warning by saying ‘_ <- doSomething [1]’
    or by using the flag -fno-warn-unused-do-bind
```

Comment: Thanks :) The list comprehension equivalent especially is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Lets turn this into the equivalent calls to `>>=`:

```
["test"] >>= (\first ->
                 doSomething [1] >>= (\_ -> return first))
```

The compiler always does this internally with `do`. The two ways of writing it are exactly the same.

Now, the `>>=` for `[]` is the same as `concatMap` with its arguments flipped, so lets go ahead and make that transformation as well (and apply the definition `return x = [x]`) and reduce:

```
concatMap (\first -> concatMap (\_ -> [first]) (doSomething [1])) ["test"]
concatMap (\first -> concatMap (\_ -> [first]) ([1] ++ [1])) ["test"]
concatMap (\first -> concatMap (\_ -> [first]) [1, 1]) ["test"]
concatMap (\first -> concat [[first], [first]]) ["test"]
concatMap (\first -> [first, first]) ["test"]
concat [["test"], ["test"]]
["test", "test"]
```

Intuitively, the `[]` Monad can be thought of as representing a "nondeterministic" computation (that is, a computation that may take on one of several different possible results). When you combine two nondeterministic computations in this way, the number of results multiply. This is due to the different "paths" that can be taken, one for each possibility at each branch.

For reference, here is the conversions between `do` notation and `>>=` and `>>` calls (note that `m1 >> m2` must always be equivalent to `m1 >>= (\_ -> m2)`):

```
do x <- m1                m1 >>= (\x ->
   m2 x                              m2 x
   ...                               ...)

do m1                     m1
   m2                     >> m2

do x                      x
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `List` monad (or `[]`) the "effect" is returning multiple results instead of one. So, your `doSomething` function doesn't contribute to the result, but does contribute to the effect, thus changing the length of the final list.